# loop function that takes the elements from two matrices and performs a calculation

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I have two matrices. One is a 36x6 matrix while the other is a 6x6.

I'd like to efficiently run this calculation:

[image]

The 36x6 matrix contains the phij elements while the 6x6 matrix contains the pij elements.

The two letters after the dash in every 6 row names of the 36x6 matrix e.g. first row name: "Aa-***Aa***", are in the same order as the row names of the 6x6 matrix.

My 36x6 Matrix looks like this:

```
                   Aa           A         Baa         Ba          B        Caa
  Aa-Aa   0.333333333 0.000000000 0.333333333 0.00000000 0.33333333 0.00000000
  A-Aa    0.250000000 0.250000000 0.000000000 0.50000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
  Baa-Aa  0.000000000 0.400000000 0.000000000 0.40000000 0.20000000 0.00000000
  Ba-Aa   0.000000000 0.333333333 0.333333333 0.00000000 0.33333333 0.00000000
  B-Aa    0.000000000 0.142857143 0.142857143 0.42857143 0.28571429 0.00000000
  Caa-Aa  0.250000000 0.000000000 0.250000000 0.25000000 0.00000000 0.25000000
  Aa-A    0.125000000 0.750000000 0.125000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
  A-A     0.055555556 0.222222222 0.222222222 0.33333333 0.11111111 0.05555556
  Baa-A   0.045454545 0.272727273 0.318181818 0.31818182 0.04545455 0.00000000
  Ba-A    0.062500000 0.125000000 0.437500000 0.31250000 0.06250000 0.00000000
  B-A     0.000000000 0.181818182 0.181818182 0.36363636 0.00000000 0.27272727
  Caa-A   0.000000000 0.125000000 0.125000000 0.37500000 0.25000000 0.12500000
  Aa-Baa  0.000000000 0.250000000 0.125000000 0.50000000 0.12500000 0.00000000
  A-Baa   0.040000000 0.120000000 0.440000000 0.16000000 0.24000000 0.00000000
 Baa-Baa 0.011764706 0.094117647 0.376470588 0.29411765 0.15294118 0.07058824
 Ba-Baa  0.013888889 0.097222222 0.236111111 0.27777778 0.27777778 0.09722222
 B-Baa   0.000000000 0.000000000 0.347826087 0.10869565 0.43478261 0.10869565
 Caa-Baa 0.052631579 0.052631579 0.210526316 0.26315789 0.26315789 0.15789474
 Aa-Ba   0.000000000 0.000000000 0.111111111 0.66666667 0.11111111 0.11111111
 A-Ba    0.000000000 0.040000000 0.160000000 0.44000000 0.32000000 0.04000000
 Baa-Ba  0.015384615 0.061538462 0.292307692 0.27692308 0.20000000 0.15384615
 Ba-Ba   0.007194245 0.028776978 0.208633094 0.35251799 0.28057554 0.12230216
 B-Ba    0.000000000 0.033783784 0.087837838 0.28378378 0.37837838 0.21621622
 Caa-Ba  0.012987013 0.012987013 0.077922078 0.28571429 0.32467532 0.28571429
 Aa-B    0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.60000000 0.40000000 0.00000000
 A-B     0.000000000 0.166666667 0.000000000 0.33333333 0.50000000 0.00000000
 Baa-B   0.046153846 0.030769231 0.076923077 0.32307692 0.26153846 0.26153846
 Ba-B    0.000000000 0.006802721 0.068027211 0.25850340 0.40816327 0.25850340
 B-B     0.005449591 0.008174387 0.051771117 0.12261580 0.49318801 0.31880109
 Caa-B   0.007380074 0.018450185 0.051660517 0.14022140 0.38745387 0.39483395
 Aa-Caa  0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 1.00000000
 A-Caa   0.000000000 0.200000000 0.000000000 0.00000000 0.60000000 0.20000000
 Baa-Caa 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.045454545 0.27272727 0.40909091 0.27272727
 Ba-Caa  0.000000000 0.023809524 0.059523810 0.13095238 0.32142857 0.46428571
 B-Caa   0.010600707 0.010600707 0.028268551 0.10247350 0.32155477 0.52650177
 Caa-Caa 0.001811594 0.003623188 0.009057971 0.05978261 0.26992754 0.65579710
```

And the 6x6 matrix looks like this:

```
                                  Period 2 Short Ratings
  Period 1 Short Ratings          Aa           A        Baa         Ba          B        Caa
                     Aa  0.088235294 0.235294118 0.23529412 0.26470588 0.14705882 0.02941176
                     A   0.044444444 0.233333333 0.30000000 0.30000000 0.06666667 0.05555556
                     Baa 0.017985612 0.082733813 0.31654676 0.24820144 0.25179856 0.08273381
                     Ba  0.006048387 0.034274194 0.15322581 0.31451613 0.31048387 0.18145161
                     B   0.007675439 0.014254386 0.05592105 0.16995614 0.42872807 0.32346491
                     Caa 0.004081633 0.008163265 0.02040816 0.08163265 0.29693878 0.58877551
    attr(,"class")
    [1] "matrix"
```

nhi is the row sum corresponding to elements in phij of the 36x6 matrix.

They come from this matrix:

```
          Aa A Baa Ba   B Caa
      A-A  1 4   4  6   2   1
     A-Aa  1 1   0  2   0   0
      A-B  0 1   0  2   3   0
     A-Ba  0 1   4 11   8   1
    A-Baa  1 3  11  4   6   0
    A-Caa  0 1   0  0   3   1
     Aa-A  1 6   1  0   0   0
    Aa-Aa  1 0   1  0   1   0
     Aa-B  0 0   0  3   2   0
    Aa-Ba  0 0   1  6   1   1
   Aa-Baa  0 2   1  4   1   0
   Aa-Caa  0 0   0  0   0   1
      B-A  0 2   2  4   0   3
     B-Aa  0 1   1  3   2   0
      B-B  2 3  19 45 181 117
     B-Ba  0 5  13 42  56  32
    B-Baa  0 0  16  5  20   5
    B-Caa  3 3   8 29  91 149
     Ba-A  1 2   7  5   1   0
    Ba-Aa  0 1   1  0   1   0
     Ba-B  0 1  10 38  60  38
    Ba-Ba  1 4  29 49  39  17
   Ba-Baa  1 7  17 20  20   7
   Ba-Caa  0 2   5 11  27  39
    Baa-A  1 6   7  7   1   0
   Baa-Aa  0 2   0  2   1   0
    Baa-B  3 2   5 21  17  17
   Baa-Ba  1 4  19 18  13  10
  Baa-Baa  1 8  32 25  13   6
  Baa-Caa  0 0   1  6   9   6
    Caa-A  0 1   1  3   2   1
   Caa-Aa  1 0   1  1   0   1
    Caa-B  2 5  14 38 105 107
   Caa-Ba  1 1   6 22  25  22
  Caa-Baa  1 1   4  5   5   3
  Caa-Caa  1 2   5 33 149 362
```

I want the loop to cycle through the first 6 elements of column j in the 36x6 matrix, and for each element it subtracts the first element in the 6x6 matrix, squares the result, divides by the first element in the 6x6 matrix, multiplies the result by the row sum of the row of the current element in the 36x6 matrix and temporarily stores the 6 results? Then the loop moves down the column to the next 6 elements of row j in the 36x6 and repeats the steps. When it's done with the first column, I want it to go to column j+1 in both the 36x6 and 6x6 matrices and repeat the mentioned steps.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I've been doing it manually but I realized that I'd have to do it 216 times. So I haven't set up the loop yet.

Comment: Include the code you've used to do it manually for one chunk

Comment: I suspect that this will run much faster if you can vectorize it. That will probably require reshaping each table into long form, performing some joins, calculating, and then reshaping.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using `tidyverse` based on my reading of your question. This should calculate very fast since database joins and vectorized calculations will work faster than loops. And I think the calculation is more readable this way, too.

BTW, it's not clear to me how the last table relates, as there's no mention of nhi in the top formula. But I hope this faithfully calculates the first part of the equation, and should give an idea for how to finish.

First, I prepare long-format tables `Phij`, `Pij`, and `Phi` (see bottom). Then I join them and do the math, which is easier to follow when the elements are adjacent.

```
library(tidyverse)
output <- Phij %>%
  # Attach matching columns from Pij and Phi
  left_join(Pij, by = c("i", "j")) %>%
  left_join(Phi, by = c("h", "i")) %>%

  # Calculate first term as in equation
  mutate(first_term = ((Phij - Pij)^2) * Phi)
```

Output: this is in long format but could be reshaped using `spread`

```
> head(output)
    h  i  j      Phij        Pij Phi  first_term
1  Aa Aa Aa 0.3333333 0.08823529   1 0.060073048
2   A Aa Aa 0.2500000 0.08823529   1 0.026167820
3 Baa Aa Aa 0.0000000 0.08823529   1 0.007785467
4  Ba Aa Aa 0.0000000 0.08823529   1 0.007785467
5   B Aa Aa 0.0000000 0.08823529   1 0.007785467
6 Caa Aa Aa 0.2500000 0.08823529   1 0.026167820
```

---

Preparing long tables: I'm not 100% sure I'm interpreting the coordinates of your matrices correctly, but this should be simple to fix if so.

1) To make `Phij`, I read in the matrix as a table (note I added "hi" as first column name), split the row names into `h` and `i`, and gather the column names into a new column `j`.

```
library(tidyverse)
Phij <- read.table(stringsAsFactors = F, header = T, text = "
     hi            Aa           A         Baa         Ba          B        Caa
  Aa-Aa   0.333333333 0.000000000 0.333333333 0.00000000 0.33333333 0.00000000
  A-Aa    0.250000000 0.250000000 0.000000000 0.50000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
  Baa-Aa  0.000000000 0.400000000 0.000000000 0.40000000 0.20000000 0.00000000
  Ba-Aa   0.000000000 0.333333333 0.333333333 0.00000000 0.33333333 0.00000000
  B-Aa    0.000000000 0.142857143 0.142857143 0.42857143 0.28571429 0.00000000
  Caa-Aa  0.250000000 0.000000000 0.250000000 0.25000000 0.00000000 0.25000000
  Aa-A    0.125000000 0.750000000 0.125000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
  A-A     0.055555556 0.222222222 0.222222222 0.33333333 0.11111111 0.05555556
  Baa-A   0.045454545 0.272727273 0.318181818 0.31818182 0.04545455 0.00000000
  Ba-A    0.062500000 0.125000000 0.437500000 0.31250000 0.06250000 0.00000000
  B-A     0.000000000 0.181818182 0.181818182 0.36363636 0.00000000 0.27272727
  Caa-A   0.000000000 0.125000000 0.125000000 0.37500000 0.25000000 0.12500000
  Aa-Baa  0.000000000 0.250000000 0.125000000 0.50000000 0.12500000 0.00000000
  A-Baa   0.040000000 0.120000000 0.440000000 0.16000000 0.24000000 0.00000000
 Baa-Baa 0.011764706 0.094117647 0.376470588 0.29411765 0.15294118 0.07058824
 Ba-Baa  0.013888889 0.097222222 0.236111111 0.27777778 0.27777778 0.09722222
 B-Baa   0.000000000 0.000000000 0.347826087 0.10869565 0.43478261 0.10869565
 Caa-Baa 0.052631579 0.052631579 0.210526316 0.26315789 0.26315789 0.15789474
 Aa-Ba   0.000000000 0.000000000 0.111111111 0.66666667 0.11111111 0.11111111
 A-Ba    0.000000000 0.040000000 0.160000000 0.44000000 0.32000000 0.04000000
 Baa-Ba  0.015384615 0.061538462 0.292307692 0.27692308 0.20000000 0.15384615
 Ba-Ba   0.007194245 0.028776978 0.208633094 0.35251799 0.28057554 0.12230216
 B-Ba    0.000000000 0.033783784 0.087837838 0.28378378 0.37837838 0.21621622
 Caa-Ba  0.012987013 0.012987013 0.077922078 0.28571429 0.32467532 0.28571429
 Aa-B    0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.60000000 0.40000000 0.00000000
 A-B     0.000000000 0.166666667 0.000000000 0.33333333 0.50000000 0.00000000
 Baa-B   0.046153846 0.030769231 0.076923077 0.32307692 0.26153846 0.26153846
 Ba-B    0.000000000 0.006802721 0.068027211 0.25850340 0.40816327 0.25850340
 B-B     0.005449591 0.008174387 0.051771117 0.12261580 0.49318801 0.31880109
 Caa-B   0.007380074 0.018450185 0.051660517 0.14022140 0.38745387 0.39483395
 Aa-Caa  0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 1.00000000
 A-Caa   0.000000000 0.200000000 0.000000000 0.00000000 0.60000000 0.20000000
 Baa-Caa 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.045454545 0.27272727 0.40909091 0.27272727
 Ba-Caa  0.000000000 0.023809524 0.059523810 0.13095238 0.32142857 0.46428571
 B-Caa   0.010600707 0.010600707 0.028268551 0.10247350 0.32155477 0.52650177
 Caa-Caa 0.001811594 0.003623188 0.009057971 0.05978261 0.26992754 0.65579710") %>%

separate(hi, into = c("h", "i"), sep = "-") %>%
  gather(j, Phij, Aa:Caa)
```

2) Similar for `Pij`:

```
Pij <- read.table(stringsAsFactors = F, header = T, text = "
i        Aa           A        Baa         Ba          B        Caa
Aa  0.088235294 0.235294118 0.23529412 0.26470588 0.14705882 0.02941176
A   0.044444444 0.233333333 0.30000000 0.30000000 0.06666667 0.05555556
Baa 0.017985612 0.082733813 0.31654676 0.24820144 0.25179856 0.08273381
Ba  0.006048387 0.034274194 0.15322581 0.31451613 0.31048387 0.18145161
B   0.007675439 0.014254386 0.05592105 0.16995614 0.42872807 0.32346491
Caa 0.004081633 0.008163265 0.02040816 0.08163265 0.29693878 0.58877551") %>%
  gather(j, Pij, Aa:Caa)
```

3) I made `Phi` by summing each row (ie h/i combination) of `Phij`:

```
# Note, these are all 1, but maybe good to include to see typos in source
Phi <- Phij %>%
  group_by(h,i) %>%
  summarize(Phi= sum(Phij)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: This is great! This is very helpful. The nhi is the first variable after the last summation in the equation.